# Error in creating Segue in Interface builder in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I am trying to compile my code in Xcode 9 which was perfectly working in Xcode 8.3, now it crashes on Segue from table view to uiviewcontroller.
This is the error message.

```
2017-10-11 10:44:36.410414-0500 Dev_TenantMoveIn[307:18597] -[PDFViewController initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c80111d0
2017-10-11 10:44:36.412182-0500 Dev_TenantMoveIn[307:18597] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PDFViewController initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c80111d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x186a0fd38 ........ 0x1863fa56c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Show code for PDFViewController, please.

Comment: See the code below